# VS 2015 syntax highlighting red lines in vue files

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a .Vue file but VS 2015 keeps complaining about syntax: Here is how it shows red lines everywhere

[image]

I am on VS 2015 Update 3 Enterprise edition

How can I fix this issue? Is there any plugins required to be installed for this purpose?

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio does not have specific tooling (currently) for VueJS single file components (`.vue` files), I encountered the same Intellisense issues.

What I ended up doing is using Visual Studio Code to develop .vue files, specifically this plugin for VSCode https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=octref.vetur (Vetur)

Comment: I'm not able to make vetur work for some reason. Apparently, no one else having this problem; so I must be missing something obvious. This is what I did: 1. installed vetur, 2. downloaded veturpack, 3. ran yarn and yarn dev. Nothing works. I also tried adding a jsconfig.json file with `include": [
      "./client/**/*"
    ]` Did the same in tsconfig as well. Could you tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: I use VSCode + Vetur for syntax highlighting + intellisense + linting. To set it up, I just downloaded VSCode + Vetur, when a `.vue` is opened the features from Vetur are enabled. I don't use `veturpack` so can't provide any help there. You could try raising an issue on `veturpack`'s Github project regarding your problem.

Comment: Thanks. It's not about veturpack. Vetur just doesn't work anywhere. When you say "when a .vue is opened the features from Vetur are enabled," do you mean you have to do something to enable them, or they're automatically enabled? I'm using Windows 10 and the latest VS Code, Vetur, and Node.

Comment: It's automatically enabled, and should be auto detected when you open a `.vue` file. Check the lower right hand corner and make sure the language shows as `vue`, if it's not you can use the command palette (ctrl + shift +p) > change language > set to vue.

Comment: Solved! That was exactly the problem. I had earlier set up my .vue files to be read as html. I was tinkering with all kinds of configurations and packages to make vetur work and it never occurred to me the problem was so simple. Many thanks!